# Clear activity rendering before reusing?

Tags: android

When starting an activity (AlbumViewActivity) with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag to display a new album, I see the previous album rendered before the new one pops in.

Activity hierarchy :

AlbumViewActivity->MenuActivity->AlbumPickerActivity->AlbumViewActivity

How can I "clear" the previous render of AlbumViewActivity when a new album is picked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the new intent to be reused in the existing activity, it must be declared as a "SingleTask" or "SingleInstance" android:launchmode.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) says:

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the
>   current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that
>   activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and
>   this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a
>   new Intent.

So basically, get rid of this flag!

Comment: Clearing inbetween activities is something I need, and recycling the activity would be great, but it seems to create a new one too ( activity object seems to be a to a different address ).

Comment: If you want to recycle your activity, you need to clear it manually!

Comment: I just read the note about "standard" launch mode, recreating an instance of the Activity ... I'll try with the "singleInstance" launch mode.
Still I think it's weird to catch a glimpse of the old activity that is being destroyed.

Comment: That did the trick (with "singleTask" after reading description of all modes), clearing the view in onNewIntent().

Answer (score 0):

Simple use the  **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP** flag
before calling the activity again, will resolve your problem.

Comment: I said in my question I was using this flag ...
The problem was the launch mode of the activity, as said in the note :
`Note: If the launch mode of the designated activity is "standard", it too is removed from the stack and a new instance is launched in its place to handle the incoming intent. That's because a new instance is always created for a new intent when the launch mode is "standard".`